# Using google fonts with rails

Tags: css

I'm using ruby on rails version 5.0.0, and I'm using c9.io. I'm not that sure how to use Google fonts and where I would put the embed font code:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Delius" rel="stylesheet">
```

I know that I have to put `font-family: 'Delius', cursive;` in the css file, but if I do that without doing the previous, the only font it uses is Comic Sans.

I learned the answer but I'd still like to know which folder would you put it in?

Comment: alternatively you can add it to your application layout: `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You put `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Delius" rel="stylesheet">` in the `application.html.erb` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can import it wih CSS - Place this at the top of your css file:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Delius');
```